# decipher with RSA and homomorphic property.

Tags: rsa, encryption

I want to know how to recovery the original value of two plain values m and n with  RSA algorithm and the homomorphic properties.

I've got the following example: 
private key (d,n) = (47,143)

with the public key that is unknown, we have the following encrypted message: encrypt(m*n) = encrypt(m)*encrypt(n)= 256.

With the private key I can decipher the value 256 and get 21. But, how can I know the original values of m and n?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] is much better suited for questions like this.

Comment: What's `encrypt` supposed to be? If you mean RSA encryption, then `encrypt(n)` doesn't make sense. The value to encrypt must be smaller than the modulus.

Comment: I need to know how it works to program with python.

Comment: Then [edit] your question to make a programming question out of it, but you will need to provide more context.

Comment: There is no more context, it's a simple question. I've got the ciphered text, I've got the private key and we know the original messege was like m*n. How kann I recovery the original values of m and n with the private key. I don't want any code. I need to understand how it works.

Comment: I can answer myself. It's a simple factorization problem. With the private key, the cipher and the homomorphic properties, I can decipher and than factor the value. So I can know the original values of n and m.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer myself. It's a simple factorization problem. With the private key, the cipher and the homomorphic properties, I can decipher and than factor the value. So I can know the original values of n and m. –